# How to remove a <style> element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

so there is this website and i wanna change the latest change in style, because i think it's ugly and useless.
i located the bad part, but strangely enough i can't seem to remove it.

```
<div id="regularMenu">
<ul class='menu2'>
 <li>
    <a href="/linkA" class="notcurrent">link1</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="/linkB" class="notcurrent">link2</a>
 </li>
 <li>
    <a href="/linkC" class="notcurrent">link3</a>
 </li>
 <style>
   a, a:visited { color: #832; }
   #menu a, #menu a:visited { color: #832; }
   .menu2 li a, .menu2 li a:visited { color: #832; }
 </style>
</ul>
</div>
```

i tried

```
 $('.menu2> *:last-child').remove();
```

and

```
 $('/html/body/div[3]/div/ul/style').remove();
```

that being the css path. i copied it with firebug.
also tried it with the copied Xpath but :(

i also tried:

```
 $('a').css("color", "#269");
```

that works, but it overwrites the old css rule too. and i would rather have that preserved.

i tried looking for an answer but i couldn't find any that helped. so now im hoping someone could help me with this.

thanks!

Comment: You want to remove the whole `style` block? Or a particular style that's *within* the style block? Also, the only valid child of a list element (`ul` or `ol`) is the `li` element.

Comment: I don't think a `<style>` in a `<ul>` is valid. Are you sure the DOM is constructed in the way you're assuming?

Comment: yes i want that style block removed.  i copy/pasted the HTML part straight from the source. no idea what the author was thinking by putting a style in an ul.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried:

```
$('.menu2 style').remove();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you keep the style block, then it should remained preserved.  Use this to change the color:

```
$('a').css("color", "#269");
```

and this to change it back

```
$('a').css("color", "");
```

it should go back to the rule for an anchor tag rather than an inline style.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
$('.menu2 > style').remove();
```

[see demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/PeV5C/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.styleSheets` to find all used style sheets and when the unwanted is found, set `disabled` to true.

More information:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.styleSheets
2. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/stylesheets.html#StyleSheets-StyleSheet

As far as I can tell, it works in all modern browsers.